# Flash cs5.5 Created apk need AIR Runtime in Android Device

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5.5

i am new to action script, however i created simple app and genrated .apk with flash CS5.5, when i installed it on Android Device it didn't work with error something like (Air Required),  Problem solved when Air Runtime Installed in Android Device, **but I want my apk directly run on Android Device without installing AIR runtime on it**, i hv heared that you can embed AIR into apk (so it directly work on android device without installing AIR runtime), but i coudn't found its option in flash cs5.5 publish settings .  Kindly Help and Suggest . 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need manually create Captivate Runtime for Flash CS 5.5 (from CS6 can do the same with IDE). Read this thread:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/909784 and this http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/08/10/air-3-0-captive-runtime/

Comment: i am getting difficulty using command line, when i double click adt it opens and just vanishes.

Comment: Look this tutorial, you are doing it in the wrong way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaMLD4c0R7A

Comment: please answer this post in you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165649/deploy-in-flash-builder-4-6-actionscript-mobile-project-make-in-flash-cs5-5-an

Comment: Easiest way to create captivate runtime is to download newest Flash CC trial, or older Flash CS6 trial and create APK with it.