# Publish in flash builder 4.6 (actionscript mobile project) make in flash CS5.5 animation

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder, flash-cs5.5

I am new to action script development. However, I have learned enough action script that I can play with it. I am only interested in android development. For this purpose flash cs5.5 is my favourite but it does not provide captive runtime for .apk(and we have to use adt command line thing, i tried alot but couldn't embed air runtime through adt command line)... so I used flash builder 4.6 which is very good(multi platform development) and provide direct and easy option for captive runtime. BUT IN FLASH BUILDER you can not use timeline and animations, which is its disadvantage to me. **HERE I WANT TO KNOW, IS THIS POSSIBLE I MAKE ANIMATIONS, GRAPHICS ETC IN FLASH CS5.5 and RELEASE APP THROUGH FLASH DEVELOP(so i can use captive runtime option in FB 4.6).** OR **you can tell the easiest way to captive runtime in FLASH cs5.5 generated apk**

Answer (score 0):

You can export animation with AS Linkage to .swc libs and connect this swc`s to flash builder project.

[Export swc](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001912.html)

[Connect swc to FlashBuilder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7fe6.html)